# How to Put image on Navigation List in Oracle APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

can anyone help me? I would like to show my own Image in the Navigation List. I've already tryed it in the Shared Components / List Details / Edit Desktop Navigation menu but he didnt show my image. See Attached image

at the Page HTML shows me that he put FA in front of my image :O 
span class="fa *********/r/425/files/static/v11/2018-06-13 08_34_21-Durchführung CAB.png"

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which list template are you using?

Comment: i use the standard Desktop Navigation Menu

Comment: I think that list template "Side Navigation Menu" only supports icon classes, not images.  You could perhaps copy the list template and modify it to show images, but that might be tricky.

Comment: mhhh Okay, thank you. I Think i wont to this ...

Answer (score 1):

In this place you put class name of FontApex or custom css class which contains image info.

For example:

Image/class: slon

Inline css for page:

```
.slon {
    background-image: url(#APP_IMAGES#2.jpg);
    background-size: 35px 35px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this Idea, but it also does not work. See New_1 and New_2 Pictures :(